# Plane doesn't seem to follow rendering rules, and shadow doesn't touch object

Tags: modeling, rendering

I'm relatively new to blender. I'm following Blender Guru's tutorial on chairs and made it all the way to the rendering video. However, when I created a plane, the chair sits directly on the plane yet the shadows are offset and don't touch the base of the chair. In addition, the plane isn't reflecting back any light onto the chair. Here are some pictures further illustrating my points.

*Perspective view of chair in which you can see the light isn't reflecting off the plane, nor is the shadow connected to the chair.*

[image]
[image]

Comment: the plane isn't reflecting any light, it might be because the light is not strong enough, or maybe you've deactivate some visibility settings for this plane. About the chair that doesn't touch the plane, maybe it was touching it but you gave a Subdivision Surface modifier to the plane, it could have shifted its surface?

Comment: Are you using evee or sycles rendering engine? Is the problem visible in the rendering result, in addition to the viewport preview?

Comment: I appreciate the responses! I switched to cycles and it cleared the problem up. Thanks for helping a noob like me out.

Comment: Same problem here. Solved by changing from EvEE to Cycles. Thanks Medhi!